# On Chol Ha'moed, can you rinse containers before recycling them?

Tags: halacha, chol-hamoed, contemporary-halacha, borer-separating, environment

## Background

Most cities ask that you rinse all bottles, cans, and containers before you recycle them.

Why? Because these items may get bounced around during transport and processing. If these items explode and empty out food residue onto some paper, the paper may become non-recyclable.

Please see [this source](https://ecomyths.org/myth-you-must-rinse-all-containers-before-recycling-them/).

However, the labor category of [*borer*](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/01/01-11/) is sometimes forbidden on Chol Ha'moed.

## My question

Are you allowed to rinse your recyclable containers during Chol Ha'moed?  If so, why?

Comment: Rinsing is not *borer*, aren't you rinsing dishes on Shabbat?

Comment: I do rinse dishes on Shabbat.  But these are dishes which I want to use again in the future.  Conversely, when recycling, I rinse containers before discarding them forever in the recycling bin.  I don't want them anymore, and I want the city to take them away.

Comment: On Shabbat you have a problem of *hachana*, preparing from Shabbat for after Shabbat, which is forbidden. For this reason, some people do *not* clean the dishes from their third meals. On Hol Hamoed you don't have that law. So if anything you should be concerned about rinsing on Shabbat afternoon. In any case, as I wrote, rinsing is not *borer*